# Error al instalar autenticación básica Jetstream en Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

Estoy tratando de hacer una instalación fresca de Laravel 8 con la autenticación básica.
Trabajo hace bastante con Laravel, pero este error es nuevo para mi. Laravel básico lo instala bien pero al momento de instalar Jetstream y correr "npm install && npm run dev", tira el bendito error.

Ya intenté con npm rebuild y todo lo que es borrar node_modules y hacer npm install, y nada.
Exactamente no comprendo que sucede. El servidor es Centos7. Agradeceré ayuda al problema ya que estoy detenido con este tema hace horas.

```
    cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

    /home/miproyecto/public_html/proyecto/proyectolar/node_modules/cross-env/src/index.js:23
        )
        ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
        at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
        at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
        at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
        at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/miproyecto/public_html/proyecto/proyectolar/node_modules/cross-env/src/bin/cross-env.js:3:18)

    npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64
    npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "development"
    npm ERR! node v6.17.1
    npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'.
    npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
    npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
    npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    npm ERR!     npm bugs 
    npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     /home/miproyecto/public_html/proyecto/proyectolar/npm-debug.log

    npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64
    npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
    npm ERR! node v6.17.1
    npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script 'npm run development'.
    npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
    npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     npm run development
    npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    npm ERR!     npm bugs 
    npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     /home/miproyecto/public_html/proyecto/proyectolar/npm-debug.log
```

El orden que use para instalar Laravel fue:

1. composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel miproyecto

Dentro del proyecto:

2. composer require laravel/jetstream
3. php artisan jetstream:install livewire
4. npm install && npm run dev
5. php artisan migrate

Comment: Nos muestras el orden que seguiste para instalar jetstream por favor?

Comment: Ahi respondi editando mi pregunta original, al final de todo. Antes de instalar Jetstream sume la base de datos, como hago generalmente. Tengo node y npm en sus ultimas versiones, ya que acabo de instalarlo en el servidor, que es nuevo.

Comment: Bueno, probe generando una instalación fresca de Laravel 7 y paso lo mismo, sale el error ya publicado. Esto es un punto de inflexion porque Laravel 7 ya lo he instalado muchas veces y jamas me dio un fallo. Laravel no es el tema, entiendo que el problema esta entonces en NPM o en ultima instancia en el servidor. Inicio pruebas instalando una version mas vieja de NPM, a ver que sucede. Algunas veces lo ultimo no es lo mejor. Increible el tiempo que me esta consumiendo esto...

Comment: Encontre este link donde indica un tema de incompatibilidades entre laravel mix y laravel mismo?  https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/installation